# I have an indexing problems

Tags: arrays, assembly, count, x86-16, tasm

I need to write names from keyboard and then display them, one on each line. They should be displayed with an index before of them. For example if I write the names elena and maria the should be displayed as 1.elena 2.maria

I tried adding a counter variable but I have some errors when I try to run the program in DosBox. Can someone help me? Here is my clean label that is outputting the names:

```
 lista:
  mov  dx, offset nume
print_names:
push dx
  mov  dl, 13          ; carriage return
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  mov  dl, 10          ; linefeed
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  pop  dx
  mov dx, offset index
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h
  inc byte ptr index
  mov  dx, offset nume
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  ; (*)
  add  dx, 5 + 1
  cmp  dx, numePointer ; check if the current name is the last one
  jb   print_names
  jmp  bucla           ; return to main loop
```

Comment: What errors?  A [mcve] needs details like exactly what errors you get.

Comment: I have "Illegal use of register" type of errors. The code I presented just prints the name as they are without any index. I was wondering how I could modify it correctly to add index .

Comment: You still haven't quoted the exact error message, or which line it's happening on.  [edit] your question with that information.  All the instructions in the code you posted look valid to me, but maybe I'm overlooking something because you haven't told us where to look.

Comment: This is the label that displays the name without indexes. So basically this is before I tried addind indexes to the outputs and I thought maybe someone will tell me what I need do to. I think the idea that i started with, on adding indexes is bad, but should I post the label code that gives the errors?

Comment: This code is correct, but do show us what you have tried concerning adding the numerals.

Comment: In that code, this is my method to show indexes, but mov  dl, '0' + bx / 10 and mov  dl, '0' + bx % 10 are not permitted

Comment: Right. Those are calculations that need to be done runtime using `div` or you can just code your counter in ascii to start with.

Comment: I tried declaring an index counter, but I have the error illegal instruction on int21h in the code mov dx, offset index // mov ah, 09h // int 21h. I updated the code for you to see

Comment: punct is the following : punct db '.' ,10, '$' to just print '.' after the index

Comment: That's just a typo, you need a space so `int 21h` not `int21h`.

Comment: I saw and modified, but still no index is displayed when I output

Comment: I realised that the index and . will be shown but a newline will be printed so I updated my code again

Comment: Do not put the `afisareindex` procedure in the middle of your main code. So where are we now in terms of results? :D

Comment: I made some progress ( see the updated code ), but now when I display the names, they are just looping infinitely.

Comment: See my answer! Your reload of `offset nume` is wrong. That's the infinite loop you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition is destroying the DX pointer for the name to be displayed!
Why did you put the additional code between `proc` `endp`?
`punct db '.' ,10, '$'` does not need the **10**. Should be `punct db '.$'` or even better, combine it with *index* like in `index db '?.$'`.
And still better, combine the newline with it too:

```
lista:
  mov  dx, offset nume
print_names:
  push dx                        ; (1)
  mov  dx, offset numeIndex
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  inc  byte ptr [numeIndex + 2]  ; "1" -> "2" -> "3" ...
  pop  dx                        ; (1)

  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  add  dx, 5 + 1
  cmp  dx, numePointer ; check if the current name is the last one
  jb   print_names
  jmp  bucla           ; return to main loop

  ...

numeIndex db 13, 10, 49, 46, 36
```

Comment: I modified my code as you said and declared index db '?.$' and the indexes are shown but now the indexes are special characters not 1,2,3

Comment: The **?** sign if for you to replace by "0" or "1" depending on how you want the numbering to start.

Comment: I replaced it with 1 : index db '1$'

Comment: That's fine *if* you place `inc index` after displaying the index. I will update my answer.

Comment: I can see that it is correct, but idk why it doesn t show the indexes correct. Do you mind if I send you the full code so you try it? Maybe it has something to do with my DosBox

Comment: On the first name it prints me a smiley face instead of one and on the second it prints me a heart

Comment: Then TASM is considering your 1 as **number 1** instead of **character "1"**. Try the new code `index db 13, 10, '1.$'` Perhaps change to double quotation marks: `index db 13, 10, "1.$"`

Comment: I still have the same problem. The TASM must be reading the number 1 as something else, reffering to a special character. I tried putting 48 which is the ascii code for 1 but it didn t work either

Comment: It is strange that no matter what number I write inside the " " when I declare the index, the indexes outputs are the same. One smiley face and one heart for the first two lines

Comment: Are you using the code from my latest edit to the answer? Is *index* placed in the same data section where you have *nume*? You could try `index db 13, 10, 49, 46, 36`

Comment: I am using the code. This program gives me some headaches for 5 days now. If I write maria and elena as input names the output will be smileyface //nextline 1.maria(smileyface) //nextline 2.elena(smileyface).

Comment: Just updated my answer one more time. If that still doesn't work, then I suggest you post your complete program so I can take a look. Either make it a new post or add it to the current post *but don't overwrite what the current post contains!*.

Comment: Bro you are a legend, it works now. I rember you helped me yesterday too when i had blocked and didn't know what to do. Now I hope I can finish my code. The last thing that I need to do is to delete a name from the list by its index.